# facebook php sdk not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

i used two codes and its not working the first one :

```
    <?php
  require_once('fb/facebook.php');
  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'xxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxx',
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?php
      function render_login($facebook) {
          $canvas_page = 'http://fbbost.eb2a.com/';
          // HERE YOU ASK THE USER TO ACCEPT YOUR APP AND SPECIFY THE PERMISSIONS NEEDED BY
          $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email,user_photos,friends_photos', 'redirect_uri'=>$canvas_page));
          echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
      }

    if($user_id) {
      try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        render_login($facebook);
        echo "1";
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }
    } else {
       render_login($facebook);
       echo "2";
    }
  ?>

  </body>
    </html>
```

and the second one :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>NNN</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include "fb/facebook.php";
$facebook=new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'xxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxx',
  'cookie' => true
));

$session=$facebook->getUser();
$me=null;

if($session){
  try{
    $me=$facbook->api('/me');
    print_r($me);
  }
  catch (FacebookApiException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}

if($me){
  $logoutUrl=$facbook->getLogoutUrl();
  echo "<a href='$logoutUrl'>Logout</a>";
}
else{
  $loginUrl=$facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'publish_stream,read_friendlists'
  ));
  echo "<a href='$loginUrl'>Login</a>";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

both codes return the same error when i login :
App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login.

Comment: so first you wrote the first one doesn't work and then you say both of them return error? Confuses me.

Comment: Did you created an app in the developers site?

Comment: I Think the error means you haven't set an app on facebook developper which will respond to your request to geth url.

Comment: i created an app in the developer site and i used the id and secret of the app in the two codes and its return the same error >> sory for my bad english im arabian :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your app is not public. You need to set it to public to use it with any Facebook account other than the developer's own account. Go to "Status and Review" and make the app public.

Besides, check that you have properly setup the app domain.